# does entity framework support User Defined Data Types?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm going to be starting work on a new application soon and was looking into using Entity Framework, however the database has User Defined Data Types, from looking online it seems like EF 4 does not support User Defined Data Types.  Do anyone know if it is supported on EF5 or EF6?  I'm not able to find anything online to say whether support was added in 5 or 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is available in [Entity Framework 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253), but you'll need to become familiar with [complex types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx).